# One switch control two light (one light or both light ON)

Tags: switch

I have a two paper lanterns (exactly I have 5 but lets say 2) used as bed lamps and decorative lights. The problem is that turning all of them ON is too bright for sleeping. But for decoration as well as lighting up the room, I want all of them to be turned ON. Is there any way for me to use just one switch (1, 2, 3 gangs, ways, whatever) to switching between 1 light ON and all of lights ON.

Thanks!

Comment: Are they all connected in a daisy-chain fashion, or does each lamp have its own wire back to the switchbox?

Comment: Yes, each lamp have its own wire back to the switch.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the switch box? Also, where on this planet are you?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But how can I have a photo of the switch box when I'm asking you about what kind of switch I can buy? These light bulbs are connected in parallel to one plug now. I turn all of them ON by inserting the plug into the outlet.

Comment: Ah, s/switch box/box where they all connect to the plug....that junction's in a box, right?  Or are they all daisy-chained back to this plug?

Comment: Yes, they are connected in daisy-chain backed to the plug. It's similar to this picture with all of these colorful wire connected to one plug.

http://www.slate.com/content/dam/slate/blogs/the_eye/2013/09/130910_EYE_E27All.jpg.CROP.original-original.jpg

Comment: Right -- I take it you are rewiring this to get rid of the cords (i.e. running a permanent wiring method instead of cords and plugs)?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the switch itself involves changing the wiring, and depending on how the room is setup and wired (which you may not fully know until you start opening walls) could be quite a fair amount of work. It's also a bit strange to have multiple switches controlling multiple plugs, so it's not really something that would appeal to future owners (and in fact, may be looked at as a negative).

I'd instead skip all that, and go with "smart" bulbs. There are a number of products on the market (specific product recommendations are something we don't do here) depending on what you're looking for.

Some are simple on/off, some can control bulb color/brightness, and some have "scene" capability (where you press a single button to set all lights to a preset brightness and/or color).

#### Bluetooth / Smartphone controlled

There are many that are smartphone-controlled. Personally I think this is of very limited use -- touching a switch on the wall as I leave/enter the room is more convenient than getting my phone out of my pocket, unlocking it, finding the light control app, waiting for it to load, then adjusting the light.

The benefit is they're very cheap -- there are 100's of "brands" of a couple dozen distinct models available from China.

[image]

I do have some of these in my office at work. I use the app to adjust the color every now and then, but mostly I just use the switch on the lamp they're in to turn them on or off (and it's only me that uses them).

#### Wireless control

There are a lot of bulbs that are controllable via wireless. Some are IR (with a remote that needs line-of-sight), others are RF (no line-of-sight), and you can also get Wifi and Wifi/RF hybrids.

Nice thing about these is you can get a remote switch that can be mounted to the wall, and have multiple switches if you want. You can leave the existing switch in the room controlling overall on/off (though if turned off, you can't turn lights on from the remote), just not use it at all, or replace it with a blank faceplate.

[image] [image]

#### Plug-in systems

There are also a number of ways to remotely control power to the lamps, so you use the existing bulbs.

[image] [image]

#### "Smart home" systems

These can range from wireless remote-based products (some of which also have smartphone controls), to actually replacing your existing switch with a keypad. Some of these product lines are quite extensive, offering a mix of plug-in modules, bulbs, controllable outlets, replacement switches/dimmers (which can be controlled remotely as well as control other devices), wall-mount keypads, handheld remotes, motion sensors and smart-phone interfaces.

These types of systems can be a bit overkill for a single room, but if you ever want to get into full-house automation/control it is a good starting point.

[image] [image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Several options. Depending on existing wire method...
Simple solution may be to just add shut off switches at each light then turning switch on will only turn on the preset lights
OR
If each light has a separate conductor back to the switch adding multiple switches would work.

Comment: Thanks! But my question is if I can do that with only one switch (any kind of switch).

Comment: I'm not sure I am understanding the question. Do you want one switch that turn on one light or all lights on or turn all lights off?

Comment: I'm sorry that my question is not clear very much. Now at my home I have 5 light bulbs connected in parallel to one plug. I want a single switch that allows me to switch between three options:
1. Turning ON all of the light bulbs.
2. Turning OFF all of the light bulbs.
3. Turning ON just one of the light bulbs.

Comment: If you buy a single Decora dual switch you could connect four of the lights to one load screw and the single light to the other load screw. It would use only one space in the light switch box and cheapest way to.solve your problem but the parallel circuit will.need modified some